# Facing some unknown issue some backend jvm internal error

Tags: java, android, kotlin, jvm

I am facing some unknown issue looks like it is some internal compiler error:
these are the error when building apk:

```
Error:org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Couldn't transform method node: doResume (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)Ljava/lang/Object;:
Error:org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.AnalyzerException: Error at instruction #375 L0: Incompatible stack heights
Error:org.jetbrains.org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.AnalyzerException: Incompatible stack heights
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Icompatible stack heights - sounds like for some reason you're stack will be too large, perhaps you've got incredibly deep nested method calls? It's long shot but it appears that it has something to do with the compiler knowing the max stack depth that your code could produce at runtime and seeing that it is too large?

Comment: Or, alternatively, it maybe an issue in your version of Kotlin. See: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207772845-Community-Builds-Broken-looks-to-be-a-kotlin-compiler-bug-

Try updating your Kotlin version to see if it resolves the issue

Comment: Thanks thomas for reply i have updated kotlin but problem is intact, is there any way to encounter the issue?

Comment: If you're project isn't too large, posting the code here would help.

Comment: Thanks ThomasCook, snowe for help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After struggling for a long time I found the solution, the code which causes the problem is this:

```
  if (investorType=="Institutional")
            {linSignUp
                if (firmName.isEmpty()) {
```

There is a problem in first if block which a `linSignUp` a reference of linear layout which accidentally placed here, which should not be here.
So the View just here alone with no use,  when I removed it, the build generated successfully.

Comment: Such a simple thing. Kotlin lint team should add this.

Answer (score 2):

This was one of the most frustrating errors to track down.

Here is the error I was getting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception during code generation
Cause: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: wrong code generated
org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Couldn't transform method node:
.....
```

If your stack trace further on is related to views and strings, the main culprit for me was that the xml view id was too long.

This name caused the error: team_management_players_recycler_view_layout 
I reduced it to this: team_man_players_recycler_layout

BOOM ERROR WAS GONE!

Hope this helps someone else out!

Comment: A similar case for me but in pure java: a string variable was big (more than 500 lines with word wrap)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in **kotlin 1.3.72** and the code that was causing it was a recursive suspend function contained in a suspend function:

```
suspend fun function1(){
  suspend fun internalFun(){
   // does something
   internalFun()  //<-- this was causing the problem
  }    
  internalFun()
}
```

I fixed by rearranging the code in such a way that i hadn't to call `internalFun()` inside itself.
I don't know if the fact that they were `suspend` functions was relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Error message: "e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: wrong bytecode generated"

In my case, I used runBlocking{} in one of MainViewModel.kt's methods.

The app was compiling successfully with runBlocking{} (which I shouldn't use anyway)) until I changed the name of a parameter in that method.

I replaced runBlocking{} with viewModelScope.launch {} in order to get ride of this error message.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps others in the future, my issue was due to using my custom extension:

```
suspend operator fun <T> MutableLiveData<T>.plusAssign(newValue: T) = ...
```

It was used like this:

```
init {
    job = GlobalScope.launch {
        while (true) {
            delay(1000)
            foo += bar // This is the error.
        }
    }
}
```

Using it like this, is however, completely fine:

```
suspend fun refreshNextJob() {
    foo += bar
}
```

Not sure why this happens, but maybe this will help someone later.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception
>   during code generation Cause: Back-end (JVM) Internal error: wrong
>   code generated org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationException
>   Back-end (JVM) Internal error: Couldn't transform method node: getS
>   ()Ljava/lang/String;:   @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() //
>   invisible    L0
>       LINENUMBER 9 L0
>       NEW com/example/GsonConverter
>       DUP
>       INVOKESPECIAL com/example/GsonConverter. ()V
>       ASTORE 1    L1
>       LINENUMBER 10 L1 ...
>
> Cause: UTF8 string too large Element is unknownThe root cause was
>   thrown at: ByteVector.java:246 Cause: Back-end (JVM) Internal error:
>   Couldn't transform method node: getS ()Ljava/lang/String;:
>   @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible    L0 ...
>
> Cause: UTF8 string too large Element is unknownThe root cause was
>   thrown at: ByteVector.java:246 File being compiled at position: (8,5)
>   in
>   C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication03/app/src/main/java/com/example/myapplication/**ATest.kt**
>   The root cause was thrown at: TransformationMethodVisitor.kt:92 File
>   being compiled at position:
>   file://**C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication03/app/src/main/java/com/example/myapplication/ATest.kt**
>   The root cause was thrown at: FunctionCodegen.java:1043 ...
>
> **Cause: UTF8 string too large Element is unknown**The root cause was
>   thrown at: ByteVector.java:246 ...

I removed a class `ATest` from an application, but it didn't help. A problem was in a constant string about 80 Kb (JSON).

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just forgot to add method call when typed view name.

```
img_my_best_image
```

Instead of

```
img_my_best_image.show()
```